# Can't fetch data from SQL Server after connection

Tags: sql, windows, port, firewall

I have strange problem.
I wrote app which connects to SQL database and fetch data from it. 2 days ago at one of my computers (when I login on user account) it stoped to fetch data but it is connecting to server. When I login on same computer on admin account it is working normally. I tried to block the Windows Defender on the user account but nothin changes. Any ideas what could be wrongly changed on that account?

Answer (score 0):

So finally what I did is I deleted the user and setup it again.
After it it was working normally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).